# Is there a way to make multiple buttons and views anchored whilst panning and zooming?

Tags: java, android

Say I had multiple buttons and an that I wanted to be able to pan and zoom across, for instance, a map image with buttons that show key locations. I need to be able to zoom in and pan over that map image whilst the buttons maintain their relative positions Im new to android development so this is probably simple but I was wondering what would be the best way to try this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just trying to be clear you want to implement multiple buttons in a view and use those buttons to navigate. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Sort of, I need the buttons to keep their place relative to the map when you zoom or move the image, for instance, the button over a particular hill needs to stay over the hill when the user pans across it. But the map is an image rather than a map object

Comment: You can use the floating action button. If you want I can give you link as how to implement it in your application

Comment: I'm not sure this is exactly what I need but ill look into it. I'm more concerned about how I would I'm more concerned about how I could keep the button anchored to a position on the image when the image is zoomed and moved. Thanks for the info either way ill take a look

Comment: It would probably help to include what map library you're using.

Comment: I'm not using a map library, I have my own custom image that I am using for the map and it is currently an imageview. I couldn't figure a way to use a map library that would allow me to use my custom image as the map